# Twice the product of the terms gone from summand.

Tags: summation, hypothesis-testing

I'm having a hard time trying to understand why in the below expression the product of the terms is gone and only the squared terms is left inside the summation. [image]

The image is taken from a pdf file about Likelihood Ratio tests ([here](http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/LRT.pdf), page 4). The same approach is found on many other sources including my professor's, but I haven't found an exhaustive explanation.

Comment: I guess you're right, if you're not familiar with the topic it may appear confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just some algebra with the mixed terms using that

- $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i = n\bar X$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)(\bar X - \mu_0) = \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i\bar X - \mu_0X_i-\bar X^2 + \mu_0\bar X)$$
$$= n\bar X\bar X - \mu_0 n \bar X - n\bar X^2 + n\mu_0\bar X = 0$$

So, all mixed terms cancel each other.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that simple trick :)

Comment: @user3501165 : You are welcome. I have the same problem with forgetting simple tricks once in a while :-).